# Can I fetch data from within the program?

Tags: anchor, account

If I generate PDA within my program like this:

```
let (pda,_) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[
    &(game_data.id).to_be_bytes(),
    game_data.key().as_ref()
], &ID);
```

Can I fetch the field, let say 'pubkey' of the account associated with the pda if I don't pass this account in the account validation block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All accounts that are used within a program must be presented upfront. That is part of the account model on Solana and helps with the runtime.

You cannot fetch data from the PDA within the program. The PDA must be passed at the beginning so the runtime knows what accounts to provide.

Comment: They're just looking to use the public key as part of the seeds.  Since it's just the public key being used there's no need for the whole account info to be loaded

Comment: @HenryE actually they also use `game_data.id` which is presumably data

Comment: The original question stated "fetch data" which is not possible. Updated, my answer is no longer relevant

Comment: Hmmm, i see what you mean now by their frequent use of the word fetch. If it turns out that I totally messed with the question and misinterpreted it, i will definitely revert back the edits. Sorry! I will say though that it does seem like the question asker is aware that all data used in the seeds needs to come from somewhere. It can't just be loaded from the ether! Although there's always consts

Comment: Ok, I agree with the interpretation and rolled back the edits. Even still though they can use data from within the program in the seeds, people use constants this way for program state

Answer (score 1):

So long as you store the pubkey of the account associated with the PDA on the PDA account itself or on another account that is loaded, you can access that Pubkey and use it in the PDA seeds.

To phrase the answer another way, `find_program_address` uses an array of u8s as the seeds. All you need is to create the correct array of u8s. Therefore, even if you use a public key as part of the seeds, there's no need to load the account info of that public key so long as you have access to pubkey from somewhere else, namely stored in account. e.g.

```
#[account]
pub struct Metadata {
    authority: Pubkey,
    game_data: Pubkey,
}
```

Alternatively you can store constants, such as strings or public keys, in the program itself and use them in seeds.

```
pub const USDC_MINT: Pubkey = pubkey!("EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v");
pub const MARKET: &str = "market";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it clears lots of things but this isn't actually what I was looking for. I wanted to retrieve state of the account associated with the pda directly from the program. I had this misunderstanding that if I generate PDA within the program, it can also make call to the account even if the account isn't passed to the context.
However, I have read more about account model and program structure now and turns out my question was a stupid one.

Comment: Damn, so you really did want to try and load up an account inside the program without passing in the account via the instruction

Comment: Guilty as charged:D